# An evaluation of a summation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

$a>1, \ 1\leq k\leq N-1$
$$\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}(N-k)^vk^{-v-1}\leq C \frac{1}{N}$$where $C$ is a constant related to $a$ and is independent of $k$ and $N$.

Comment: It is not possible, since the LHS is unbounded for large $N$ with $k, a$ fixed, while the RHS tends to $0$.

Comment: Have you tried using the sum of geometric series?

Comment: Yes, you are right. This come from a paper, maybe I need to email to the author. Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes. Sorry for that, there is a mistake in that paper, so this formula is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Proceeding naively,

$\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}(N-k)^vk^{-v-1}\leq C \frac{1}{N}
$

Let
$N-k = b$.

$\begin{array}\\
s(b, k, a)
&=\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}b^vk^{-v-1}\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}(\frac{b}{k})^v\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\dfrac{(\frac{b}{k})^a-1}{\frac{b}{k}-1}\\
&=\dfrac1{k}\dfrac{(\frac{b}{k})^a-1}{\frac{b}{k}-1}\\
&=\dfrac{(\frac{b}{k})^a-1}{b-k}\\
\end{array}
$

Note that if
$b=k$
(or $N = 2k$)
then
$s(k, k, a)
=\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}k^vk^{-v-1}
=\frac1{k}\sum_{v=0}^{a-1}1
=\frac{a}{k}
=\frac{2a}{N}
$.

If $N > 2k$,
so
$b > k$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s(b, k, a)
&=\dfrac{(\frac{N-k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{(\frac{k+N-2k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{(1+\frac{N-2k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&\ge\dfrac{(1+\frac{a(N-2k)}{k})-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{\frac{a(N-2k)}{k}}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{a}{k}\\
\end{array}
$

If $N < 2k$,
so
$b < k$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
s(b, k, a)
&=\dfrac{(\frac{N-k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{(\frac{k+N-2k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{(1+\frac{N-2k}{k})^a-1}{N-2k}\\
&=\dfrac{1-(1+\frac{N-2k}{k})^a}{2k-N}\\
\end{array}
$